# Show scrollbar if content exceeds the size of the container without fixed size

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a masterpage that looks like this:

```
<body id="body" runat="server" style="padding: 0px 25px 25px 25px;">
<div class="wrapper">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <uc1:Header ID="header" runat="server" />
    <div style="width: 100%;" class="borderContent">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;">
            <uc2:MenuLeft ID="menuLeft" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 80%; float: left; margin: 20px;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="push">
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>
        Copyright (c) 2012</p>
</div>
```

In the content place holder I have a table with two rows, one is a header, the other one is the content. I would like to keep the footer in place and the content in place and with scrollbars if the content is longer than the height of the screen, but without saying how big the container is (I would like it to keep it's ratio regardless of the size of the monitor). So maybe it can be done somehow with percents?

Thanks

Comment: overflow:scroll gives me a scroll, but without a height, it stays as long as the content

Comment: for this you need to set max-height

Comment: that is exactly the thing. I don't know what is the max height. for example 400px could be good for a 15" monitor, but for a 23"? so I waould like to avoid that, and do something like container height=80% of the page instead of max-height: 400px;

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
position: absolute;
```

on  your footer and content, and then for your footer do

```
bottom: 0px;
height: 100px;
```

and then for the content do

```
bottom: 100px;
overflow: auto;
```

Which will keep the footer at the bottom of the page and the content will be above it, no matter how the page is resized.

This of course is just a guideline, you'll have to play with it to make it look like you want.

Comment: I managed to make something of my page on jsfiddle(more or less, but I think enough to make an idea). http://jsfiddle.net/4xdBk/3/ . If you stretch it all the way to the left the content will get on the right side of the menu. when I use what you sent, the content gets over everything, and outside that border that surounds the menu and the content...

Comment: Is this more what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/TT4qf/1/ I removed the table - it really shouldn't be necessary.  Also note the changes in the css.

Comment: not really...the whole thing has to be inside the containter. There is a div that has a bordercontent class. the whole thing covers the border, it doesn't stay inside.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this before, you could put some JS/jQuery on the load of the page.  Basically you will want to:

1. Calculate the max-height of the container based on % of page, or fixed amount if you prefer.
2. Append the data to the contianer
3. Determine if the container is now greater than the value retrieved in step 1.
4. If the container is greater than the content, add 'overflow-y: scroll' to the element's style
5. Else, leave as be.